# pulling from another branch doesn't recognize changes when second

Tags: git, github

I have three branches, branch1, branch2 and main, I pulled from remote branch2 to branch1, accepted some changes and declined some, after that I changed my mind and from the changes I declined I wanted to merge some, but every time I try to pull from remote branch2 git doesn't recognize the changes and it tells me that it's already up to date, what should I do to get these changes?

Comment: To put it simply, if a branch is _merged_, then to git that work is _settled_ and git won't consider the differences that are already _merged_ anymore.

Comment: Now.... to get you past the point where you are, you should go back to the merge commit and try to amend it. It's not like you can tell git to merge again,,,, you should be able to compare with the parent branches and modify to your desires.... then add all changed and run `git commit --amend --no-edit`. That will give you a new modified merge with what you really want to have there (and I am assuming you are on your own and not modifying something from a branch that other people are using already).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Git doesn't traffic in "changes". It traffics in *commits*.

So if your goal now is to merge some existing commits into your branch1, the simplest solution is just to cherry-pick those commits right onto the end of your branch1. That loses the history of where those commits originated, but it gets you the effect of those commits into the state of your branch.

If you wanted to do this more formally you could make a whole new branch, cherry pick the commits into that, and *then* you would be able to pull / merge that into your local branch, because they are different from the original commits.